# Polymer: vulcanizing/minifying site breaks it in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, minify, polymer-1.0

I have a custom build process for a Polymer site (Polybuild kept consistently breaking it for everyone). It takes the entry points into my application and runs them through `vulcanize` and a minifier. The output is a flat html file with large sections minified. CSS is not minified because the minifier broke the new syntax.

The output HTML works correctly in Chrome, however it does not work in Firefox. The site does not load and the following is logged in console:

```
TypeError: document.registerElement is not a function
 localhost:3000:1:4877
TypeError: Polymer.Base._getExtendedPrototype is not a function
 localhost:3000:1:1090
TypeError: this._desugarBehaviors is not a function
 localhost:3000:1:2359
<snip repeated desugarBehaviors error>
```

Can you tell me why would the built version not work in one browser but work in another, and why is it Firefox that fails? I do not get these errors in Chrome.

My build process is as follows:

**build.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

build_html ( ) {
  ./node_modules/.bin/vulcanize --inline-css --inline-scripts $1.html > build/$1.pre.html
  ./minify-html.js build/$1.pre.html build/$1.html
}

echo 1. clean build dir
rm -r ./build
mkdir build

echo 2. copy assets in background
cp -r assets/ build/ &

echo 3. vulcanize and minify entry points
build_html index
build_html register
rm build/*.pre.html

echo 4. copy polyfills
mkdir -p ./build/bower_components/{classlist,webcomponentsjs}
cp ./bower_components/classlist/classList.min.js ./build/bower_components/classlist
cp ./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-lite.min.js ./build/bower_components/webcomponentsjs
cp ./bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.min.js ./build/bower_components/webcomponentsjs
```

**minify-html.js**

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var hmin = require('html-minifier');
var fs = require('fs');

var src = fs.readFileSync(process.argv[2]).toString();
var res = hmin.minify(src, {
  removeComments: true,
  removeCommentsFromCDATA: true,
  collapseWhitespace: true,
  conservativeCollapse: true,
  minifyJS: true,
  preventAttributesEscaping: true,
  minifyJS: true,
  customAttrAssign: [ /\$=/ ]
});

fs.writeFileSync(process.argv[3], res);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is most likely that you're missing the webcomponents library, which might polyfill registerElement on some browsers. Make sure you're importing it everywhere it's required.

Comment: Turns out this may have been the case. I have previously been loading the library dynamically as part of a feature detection script, but I either loaded it too late. I moved it to a script tag placed before the first html import and it works again, both in the unbuilt and built version.